# Search in php and mysql with inner join

Tags: php, mysql

I am not a backend dev but a front end, yet I am trying to create a simple php search, I have followed the [tutorial on here](https://owlcation.com/stem/Simple-search-PHP-MySQL) and made the changes for the deprecated bits it had. I have a database with sub rows and columns and I am trying to get some of the data from them:

The first thing is I created the html

```
      <form action="search.php" method="GET">
        <input type="text" name="query" />
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
      </form>
```

Then the php bit:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "USER", "PSW", "DBNAME") or die("Error connecting to database: ".mysqli_error());
$query = $_GET['query']; 

$min_length = 3;

if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){

    $query = htmlspecialchars($query); 

    $query = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $query);


    $raw_results = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM article
        WHERE (`title` LIKE '%".$query."%') ") or die(mysqli_error($con));

    if(mysqli_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){

        while($results = mysqli_fetch_array($raw_results, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
            echo "<p><h3>".$results['page_id']."</h3>".$results['title']."</p><p>".$results['space']."</p>";
        }

    }
    else{
        echo "No results";
    }

}
else{
    echo "Minimum length is ".$min_length;
}
```

The above is fine and it gives me the ***article title*** and ***article id*** I have within my DB. Yet I need to get the `space` and the `year`. Attached is the DB structure:

[image] and [image]

By reading around and by looking at what my backend dev did back then, i can see this line somewhere else which should get on the right track if it ever helps.

```
$query = "SELECT A.id AS article_id, A.title AS title, C.name as space, A.page_id, T.year, T.month, T.id as time_id FROM article AS A INNER JOIN space AS S ON S.article_id = A.id INNER JOIN country AS C ON C.id = S.country_id INNER JOIN time AS T ON A.id = T.article_id WHERE (T.year BETWEEN ".$year_start." AND ".$year_stop.") GROUP BY A.title, C.name";
```

Comment: i cannot seem to locate the `space` column

Comment: @Akintunde007 see first image, the last open bit is space

Comment: @rob.m the column name in space table is original_name  and not name right. And did you execute the query what is the result?

Comment: @Shyamala if i do echo `"<p><h3>".$results['page_id']."</h3>".$results['title']."</p><p>".$results['original_name']."</p>";` i get no name for the space, no erros

Comment: @rob.m did u change c.name as c.original_name  in the query not in php  ?

Comment: @Shyamala nope, because I did not add the `$query =..` as I don't know where to insert it, they are two codes. I gave that line as an example, could you put it together in an answer?

Comment: @rob.m ok sure give the list of columns you need as query result and the table structure

Comment: @Shyamala i need the results for title, space (original_name), Time (year)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
SELECT * FROM article
    WHERE (`title` LIKE '%".$query."%')
```

with this

```
SELECT s.original_name as location, a.title, a.page_id, t.year from space s,article a, time t where a.id = s.article_id and s.article_id = t.article_id and a.title LIKE '%".$query."%'
```

This query will help you display the required columns from php.